# Relative homology and isomorphisms for spheres and hemispheres.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $i:(U, \mathbb{S}^{n-2}) \to (\mathbb{S}^{n-1}, L)$ where $U = \{x \in  \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \mid x_n \ge 0 \}$ and $ L= \{x \in  \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \mid x_n \le 0 \}$. Show that the induced map on homology is an isomorphism.

So to show that $i_\ast: H_q(U, \mathbb{S}^{n-2}) \to H_q(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}, L)$ is an isomorphism one usually would show that the maps $i : U \to \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and $i\vert_{\mathbb{S}^{n-2}} : \mathbb{S}^{n-2} \to L$ are homotopy equivalences, but in this case this simply isn't true as with $i : U \to \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ the domain is contractible and the target is not and likewise for the latter one except that the target is contractible and the domain not.

I'm beginning to think that this is not a true result in the first place as it seems that even excision cannot be used either because $U \approx D^n$, but $\mathbb{S}^{n-2} \approx \partial D^{n-1}$.

I've also looked at the long exact sequences and even though there are few contractible spaces and spheres it still doesn't give the conclusion even when trying to invoke something like the $5$-lemma. Is this a true result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think excision *can* be used here, although we have to exercise some care.

Naively, one might attempt to use excision by defining $V \subset \mathbb S^{n-1}$ be the open set $\{ x \in \mathbb S^{n-1} : x_n < 0 \}$; one would then declare that $H_q(\mathbb S^{n-1}, L) \cong H_q(\mathbb S^{n-1} \setminus V, L \setminus V) = H_q(U, \mathbb S^{n-2})$ by excision. But this is not a legitimate application of excision, since the closure of this set $V$ is *not* contained in the interior of $L$.

However, we can make progress by amending our definition of $V$, so that $V$ is the open set $\{ x \in \mathbb S^{n-1} : x_n < -\epsilon \}$, where $\epsilon$ is some small positive number. Now, the closure of $V$ *is* contained in the interior of $L$, so we can validly use excision to deduce that $H_q(\mathbb S^{n-1}, L) \cong H_q(\mathbb S^{n-1} \setminus V, L \setminus V)$.

Unfortunately, having amended our definition of $V$, it is no longer the case that $S^{n-1} \setminus V = U$ and $L \setminus V = \mathbb S^{n-2}$!

But all is not lost. Although it would be incorrect to say that $( S^{n-1} \setminus V, L \setminus V)$ is *equal* to $(U, \mathbb S^{n-2})$, we *can* say that there is a *homotopy equivalence* between the pairs $(S^{n-1} \setminus V, L \setminus V)$ and $(U, \mathbb S^{n-2})$. Indeed, $S^{n-1} \setminus V$ deformation retracts onto $U$; restricting this deformation retraction to $L \setminus V$ gives a deformation retraction of $L \setminus V$ onto $\mathbb S^{n-2}$. From this homotopy equivalence of pairs, we can conclude that $H_q(\mathbb S^{n-1} \setminus V, L \setminus V) \cong H_q(U, \mathbb S^{n-2})$.